# r_1st_connections_size permission trouble

Tags: linkedin-api

We make a GET request in Postman to get the number of 1st-degree connections of an authenticated member's network, strictly following the instructions [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/connections-size):

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections/urn:li:person:{Person ID}
```

And the result is this:

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode":100,
    "message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections",
    "status":403
}
```

We already have this set of permission scopes approved and listed in the Auth area of our App:

*r_1st_connections_size*

*r_liteprofile*

since we have been accepted in LinkedIn's Marketing Developer Programs.

So, what's wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which permission scopes are you passing into your scopes query parameter when requesting an access token?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Christopher!

These are the permission scope we are passing:

`scope: ["r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress", "rw_organization_admin", "r_organization_social", "w_organization_social", "w_organization_social", "w_member_social", "r_member_social", "w_member_social", "rw_organization_admin", "w_organization_social", "r_organization_social", "r_organization_lookup", "r_ads", "r_ads_reporting", "r_targeting", "r_1st_connections_size", "r_lite_profile"]`

Comment: Thanks Maurizio! Are you also sending a request to retrieve the Person ID: GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me?projection=(id)?

Comment: Yes, @ChristopherOu!

Comment: @ChristopherOu can you suggest any other checks we can do to fix this problem?

Comment: If you haven't done so already, I suggest submitting your request to linkedin.zendesk.com

Comment: Many thanks for the suggestion, I will try to contact them!

Comment: This is the permission for the number of connections, not connections itself: r_1st_connections_size You don't have necessary permission from LinkedIn to retrieve the connections